# Should I do AMP responsive for desktop and mobile?

Tags: amp-html

We have a new SaaS product we're launching and going to keep the blog in AMP but for our landing page, how it works and pricing, any harm if we do it in AMP for both desktop + mobile?

Desktop probably doesn't add much value but we are focused on SEO + page speed.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you're comfortable being bound to the AMP ideals in browser compatibility you'll be fine to use AMP as a full framework. Currently they support most of the latest versions of most common browsers as well as Internet Explorer 11 ([supported browser info](https://www.ampproject.org/support/faqs/supported-browsers)).

Very rarely does a breaking change get through to a production AMP component, but when it does they are pretty quick to fix it. The company I work for has had their site running on AMP for about 8 months now and I'm pretty sure I have only seen 1 breaking change go through, it was resolved within the day.

At the end of the day, so long as everything you want to accomplish on your website fits within the scope of AMP you should be ok to use AMP as a framework to power both your mobile and desktop sites - less maintenance that way too.